# Get points along a vector

Tags: c++

So I'm essentially trying to do this

say I have
`float Origin[3] = {x1, y1, z1}, EndOrigin[3] = {x2, y2, z2};`

I want to get n points along a line in three dimensions like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftz73.png)
I'm trying to do this without using a vector class, just arrays. I do not know a lot about trig, so this is a little tough for me. Any help or pointers?

Comment: No trig is required, it's just linear arithmetic.

Comment: *I'm trying to do this without using a vector class, just arrays*  -- So how would using vectors be any different than using arrays?

Comment: Please, show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Because most vector classes have built in methods to assist in calculating,

Comment: You realise when developers talk about vectors they aren't the same as when mathematicians or physicists talk about vectors?

Answer (score 5):

The points on the line segment are

```
{ t*x1 + (1-t)*x2, t*y1 + (1-t)*y2, t*z1 + (1-t)*z2 }
```

where `t` is any number in the range [0, 1]. You want n points, so just pick n values between zero and one for `t` and substitute in the formula above.